# Add Buttons to Tabs and Tab area JavaFX

Tags: java, css, button, javafx, java-8

I'm searching a way to add a **Button** to a JavaFX `Tab`.

Searched the internet for it but I can't find any solution for it.

Something like the buttons in the screenshot below.

Can someone help me with it?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**To have iconed `Button`s on the `Tab`s:**

The [`setGraphic`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#setGraphic-javafx.scene.Node-) method of `Tab`can be used to add any `Node`to be displayed on the `Tab`. A `Button` can be added as it is a `Node`.

After this a fully functional button is present, but it does not display any icon. `Button` also has the [`setGraphic`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setGraphic-javafx.scene.Node-) method which works the same, therefore an `ImageView` can be added to display an `Image` on the `Button`.

**To have control `Button`s on the top-right corner of the tab-area:**

These buttons can be placed **on the `TabPane`**, rather than inside the `TabPane`. For this you can use an `AnchorPane` to anchor the `Button`s to the top-right corner.

**Example:**

```
public class ButtonedTabPane extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.UNAVAILABLE);

        // HBox of control buttons
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(createTabButton("min.png"), createTabButton("max.png"));

        // Anchor the controls
        AnchorPane anchor = new AnchorPane();
        anchor.getChildren().addAll(tabPane, hbox);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(hbox, 3.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(hbox, 5.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(tabPane, 1.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(tabPane, 1.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(tabPane, 1.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(tabPane, 1.0);

        // Create some tabs
        Tab tab = new Tab("Files");
        tab.setGraphic(createTabButton("files.png"));
        ((Button) tab.getGraphic()).setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("I'll show the list of files!"));
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);

        tab = new Tab("Network");
        tab.setGraphic(createTabButton("network.png"));
        ((Button) tab.getGraphic()).setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("I'll show the network!"));
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);

        root.setCenter(anchor);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Button createTabButton(String iconName) {
        Button button = new Button();
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResource(iconName).toExternalForm(),
                16, 16, false, true));
        button.setGraphic(imageView);
        button.getStyleClass().add("tab-button");
        return button;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The only thing left to remove the default background and borders from the `Button`s. This can be done by inserting the following CSS selectors into your CSS stylesheet.

*style.css*

```
.tab-button {
    -fx-border-width: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-content-display: graphic-only;
}

.tab-button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
```

*The result:*

Comment: Tnx that did the job