# Buttons in TabPane using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Is there a way in JavaFX 8 to put buttons into a TabPane as shown in the mockup below? If it is possible, I only want to use a FXML file.
[image: mockup]

Comment: You could put both the `TabPane` and the `Button`s inside an `AnchorPane` - simple and straight-forward. It may become a bit messy if you will have many tabs, or the window becomes too narrow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Buttons to Tabs and Tab area JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721760/add-buttons-to-tabs-and-tab-area-javafx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at the question and answer of "[Add Buttons to Tabs and Tab area JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721760/add-buttons-to-tabs-and-tab-area-javafx)", it was not difficult to adapt it that it works with a FXML file.

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="mypackage.Controller">
    <children>
        <TabPane tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0">
            <tabs>
                /* the code for the tabs goes here */
            </tabs>
        </TabPane>
        <HBox AnchorPane.topAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0">
            <children>
                <Button text="Export..." />
                <Button text="Generate" />
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The result is shown in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After working several weeks only with the scene builder and on the FXML file for an application a few months ago, i tried to do a similar thing but i didn't succeed in trying a way to do it because i think that space on the top is reserved if you want to add some tabs, i solved my matter in inserting in the desired tabs the buttons i would had there, here is an example of what i did:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaayP.png)

I hope it is useful to you too