# JavaFX- how to hide tab content area and show only tab headers on selection of specific tab

Tags: java, javafx

I want to provide a way for users to hide/ unhide tab pane contents without adding additional buttons to UI. One way I thought was to provide a "dummy" tab in tabpane and on selecting it, all contents of tabpane will be hidden, except for headers. On selecting any other tab, contents will be made visible again. I have tried changing min/max/pref width of tabpane.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the [max height](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#maxHeightProperty) of the `TabPane`:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private static final int TABPANE_HEADER_HEIGHT = 29;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        // Add simple tabs
        TabPane tp = new TabPane();
        tp.getTabs().add(new Tab("Tab1", new Label(" Content of the first tab")));
        tp.getTabs().add(new Tab("Tab2", new Label(" Content of the second tab")));

        // Create the Tab which hides the content
        Tab hideTab = new Tab("Hide", new Label(" Content of the third tab"));
        tp.getTabs().add(hideTab);

        hideTab.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, oldval, newval) -> 
            tp.setMaxHeight(((newval) ? TABPANE_HEADER_HEIGHT : -1)));

        root.setTop(tp);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
        scene.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*Result:*

[image]

---

**Note**

You can do the same using CSS by adding a new pseudo-class for `.tab-pane` called e.g. `tabcontenthidden`. In this pseudo class the max height of the `TabPane` is the height of the tabs.

*style.css*

```
.root {  TAB_HEADER_HEIGHT: 29; }

.tab-pane:tabcontenthidden { -fx-max-height: TAB_HEADER_HEIGHT; }

.tab-pane {
    -fx-max-height: -1;
    -fx-background-color: orange;
}
```

In the Java code, you can create a `PseudoClass` like

```
PseudoClass TABPANE_CONTENT_HIDDEN = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("tabcontenthidden");
```

and you can activate this pseudo-class with the `pseudoClassStateChanged` method:

```
tabPane.pseudoClassStateChanged(TABPANE_CONTENT_HIDDEN, true); // false to show
```

---

**Note2**

You can add `Button`s to the tab area like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721760/add-buttons-to-tabs-and-tab-area-javafx/37722474#37722474) (one button to hide and show) which maybe more ergonomic than an additional `Tab`.