# Is there a way to add button to the right side of TabPane's TabControlButtons?

Tags: javafx

This is not the duplicate of [Add Buttons to Tabs and Tab area JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721760/add-buttons-to-tabs-and-tab-area-javafx) as that question and answer does not address the TabControlButtons' position.

Fxml file:

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="...TabsPresenter"> 
    <TabPane fx:id="centerTabPane" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0"> </TabPane> 
    <Button text="XYZ" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="2.5"/> 
</AnchorPane>
```

Above fxml file causes the TabControlButtons to be blocked by my new button. However, I would like to have my new button to be on the right side of TabControlButtons.

So, I tried to move the TabControlButtons to the left side of its default position.

I was able to do so with CSS.

```
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area
{
      -fx-padding: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
}
```

However, the TabControlButtons appear above of tab's headersRegion as:
[image]

Is there a way to make TabControlButtons in between the headersRegion and my new button?

Comment: @fabian can you remove the duplicate tag?

Comment: Make the question stand on it's own (i.e. include code allowing the to reproduce the issue), and I'll reopen the question, if you `@ping` me again...