# How to add close button to all tabs but one in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a tab system, with similar function to tabs in Chrome, where there is a cross on each tab to close it, like this:
[image: How google chrome does it.]

With JavaFX, I can get close, by setting the tabpane closing policy to `ALL_TABS`. Unfortunately this means my new tab button (also a tab iself) can be closed:

[image: Outcome of using ALL_TABS. Not ideal.]

I am aware of the `SELECTED_TAB` rule, which would fix this problem, but this would defeat the purpose. I am not aware of any other closing policy that would allow exceptions to the `ALL_TABS` rule.

I tried adding my own cross to each tab individually using the `setGraphic` method for the `Tab` class, however I couldn't figure out how to handle that mouse click event such that it closed the correct tab.

I realise I could also make the new tab button something other than a tab, but I wouldn't really know how to integrate that with the tab pane.

So, is there a simpler method that I'm not seeing? If not, then how can I achieve this kind of tabbing system in JavaFX?

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What happens if you set [`Tab.closeable`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#closableProperty) to `false`?

Comment: Note: After a quick test, using `tab.setCloseable(false)` will remove the close button. However, I don't believe this will function how you want it to. The tab is still a "real tab", which means it can be selected as if it contains content. You want something more like a button, but I'm not sure you could simply implement that the way you want (i.e. flush with the tab header region) when using the default `TabPaneSkin`.

Comment: You can do this using an `AnchorPane`. Check out [this question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721760/add-buttons-to-tabs-and-tab-area-javafx) which will get you what you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plusTab.setClosable(false);
```

I did a simple skim of the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#setClosable(boolean)). Will this work?

Comment: I read the closing policy documentation and the way it's worded made it sound like this kind of method wouldn't exist, so I didn't even think to look for it. Cheers :)